# Datatable info footer is displayed twice

Tags: javascript, datatables

i'm using DataTable and now after some work my table has a double datatable info showing as :

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 385 entries

Showing 1 to 10 of 385 entries
```

And i don't know how it is happening, in the inspect mode i have :

```
<div class="dataTables_info" id="tableResult_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 385 entries</div>

<div class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 385 entries</div>
```

My table is initialized like this :

```
let matable = $('#tableResult').DataTable({
            data: newData,
            dom: 'Blfrtipi',
            select: true,
            responsive:true,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Tous"]],
            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets':[column],
                    'createdCell': function (td) {
                        $(td).attr('class', 'text-center');
                    }
                }
            ],
            buttons: [
                'excel',
                {
                    className: 'boutonCacherLogsMessages',
                    text: 'Cacher logs et messages',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                       cacherMessages();
                       cacherLogs();
                    }
                }
            ],
            language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ résultats",
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Rechercher"
            },

        });
```

Can i have your help please ?
Ty

EDIT : Ok lol i found it fast it was because of the

```
dom: 'Blfrtipi',
```

where the last i was in too much

Comment: please show the actual html

Comment: i found the solution x) ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lol i found it fast it was because of the

```
dom: 'Blfrtipi',
```

where the last i was in too much